# Can't get React Router to work with this simple example

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, react-router, babeljs

I've tried as much as possible to do the same as in these [react-router examples](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples) but didn't get it working.

I have this code:

In `server.js`:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on http://localhost:5000, Ctrl+C to stop')
});
```

In `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Routing</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="dist/js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in `main.js` ("browserified" and transformed with "babelify"):

```
import React from 'react'
import { createHistory, useBasename } from 'history'
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router'

import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Main from './components/Main'

const history = useBasename(createHistory)({
    basename: '/'
});

const App = React.createClass({
    render ()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar description="Testando..." />
                <Link to="/main">Go to main</Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

React.render((
    <Router history={history}>
        <Route path='/' component={App}>
            <Route path='/main' component={Main} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
),
document.body);
```

And when I click in link Go to Main, I get this error: `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://main/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://localhost:5000'.`

What's wrong?

P.S.: I'm using **React version 0.13.3** and **react-router version 1.0.0-rc1**

---

**EDIT** - 10/09/2015 (after @knowbody 's answer)

I've changed my `server.js` to:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
const app = express()

// serve static assets normally
app.use(express.static(__dirname))

// handle every other route with index.html, which will contain
// a script tag to your application's JavaScript file(s).
app.get('*', function (request, response){
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(port)
console.log("server started on port " + port)
```

---

**EDIT** - 10/10/2015

Updated `index.html` from

```
<script src="dist/js/main.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="/dist/js/main.js"></script>
```

because I was having problem with URLs with two segments.

Comment: any reason you'r not using react-router 0.13.3?

Comment: The current version seems to be easier to use. Do you think it might be a problem with this version?

Comment: I think that there is a reason why the versions are the same, try using the 0.13.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `useBasename`. Instead just use:

```
let history = createHistory()
```

This will allow you to use [`BrowserHistory`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#createbrowserhistory).

Comment: This works only if I put `<Route path='main' component={Main} />` outside `<Route path='/' component={App}>`.

Comment: This works only if I put `<Route path='main' component={Main} />` outside `<Route path='/' component={App}>`.

Comment: no it should work just fine. aren't you forgetting about `{ this.props.children }`? see the documentation, it should make it clear for you

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much, @knowbody! I was totally lost, trying to get it right for days.